# Pass a value by onclick function to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a code in PHP like below:

```
 $rate = "<div class=\"example-\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"wallpost(".$id.")\"></div></br>;
```

and jquery like this:

```
  $('.example-').ratings(5).bind('ratingchanged', function(event, data) {

function wallpost(pass){
var a = pass;

}

        $.post('count.php',{rate:data.rating,wallpostid :a},function(data){

        alert(data);

        });

});
```

I want pass the $id value when I rate something to the jquery and then pass $id value and how many star I rate to the 'count.php' by using $.post.

When I try the code above , it can't rate.

What is my problem?

Comment: put "wallpostid" function outside of document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the `wallpostid` method

```
$rate = "<div class=\"example-".$id." \" data-postid=\"".$id."\"></div></br>Post id: <span class=\"example-rating-".$id."\">".$id."</span>";
```

and

```
$('[class^="example-"]').not('[class^="example-rating-"]').ratings(3).bind('ratingchanged', function (event, data) {
    var child = $(this).find('[class^="example-rating-"]');
    child.text(data.rating);

    $.post('count.php', {
        rate: data.rating,
        wallpostid: $(this).data('postid')
    }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank for ur comment,I ahve edit the question, hope u can give me some opinion of this question regard for my understanding. Actually I just know basic of php and jquery. Can u show me how to include the onclick function in the jquery?